# deployment script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have created deployment script using database project.
I have also created empty database in my sql and have run that script to check.
The script was executed successfully but when i see the database then no table was created.
so any idea how to use the script and what was the reason why the tables was not created.

Comment: if object_id('table') = null?

Comment: The database project has a setting which decided `When the project is run whether to only create the deployment script or run it against a database`. The default setting is only to create the script. You may want to change that to run the script

Comment: yes i want to change that setting please guide me how to do that?

Comment: @Jaidka - Try this and see if it helps: 1) Right click on DB Project and select Properties  2) Click on the Deploy Tab   3) Change the Deploy Action to "Create a deployment script (.sql) and deploy to the database"